# How does a STL multimap differ from a .NET Dictionary<key, List<values>>?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a problem where I need a .NET dictionary that supports multiple items per key. In the past I've used the STL multimap in my C++ programs. How does the design of a multimap differ from a dictionary of lists i.e. performance, size, etc. (excluding generics vs. templates)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multimap.count`: `O(log n + m)` where `n` is number of keys and `m` is number of items associated with a given key.

For a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` the equivalent functionality would be:

```
int count = dictionary[key].Count;
```

And safer is to say

```
int count;
List<TValue> list;
if(dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list)) {
    int count = list.Count;
}
```

This is an `O(1)` operation because lookup is `O(1)`<sup>1</sup> and `List<T>.Count` is `O(1)`.

`multimap.find`: `O(log n)` where `n` is number of keys

For a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` the equivalent functionality would be:

```
List<TValue> elements = dictionary[key];
```

And safer is to say

```
List<TValue> list;
if(dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list)) {
    // safe to iterate list
}
```

This is `O(1)`. See the previous remark on lookup by key in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

`multimap.insert`: `O(log n)` where `n` is the number of keys.

For a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` the equivalent functionality would be:

```
// value is TValue to insert
List<TValue> list;
if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list)) {
    list = new List<TValue>();
    dictionary.Add(key, list);
}
list.Add(value);
```

This is usually `O(1)` but can be `O(n)` when the capacity of the dictionary must be increased to accomodate the new element.

`multimap.remove`: There are three overloads of this method; I will only consider the one that accepts a key and removes all occurrences of that key from the multimap. This is an `O(log n + m)` operation where there `n` keys and `m` objects associate with a given key.

For a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` the equivalent functionality would be:

```
 dictionary.Remove(key);
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac.aspx): "This method approaches an O(1) operation." Same comment applies.

<sup>1</sup>: From the documentation: "Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to `O(1)`." Why the documentation is vague on this point is confusing to me. Either an operation is `O(1)` or it isn't. There is no such thing as "close" to `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

multimap: 
  insert/remove operations take logarithmic time Big-O(log n), 
  lookup take constant time Big-O(1).

Each element is accessed using a key value, unlike the map, a multimap key value needs not be unique, associated values do not need to be unique. The map orders the elements by their keys using a stored function key_compare, which simply does a less-than comparison.

[Here's](http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable)
an article on IDictionary performance which doesn't mention any Big-O performance metrics but does give some practical runs using the dictionary.

Comment: Of course the documentation for `IDictionary` does not mention any asymptotic guidelines; an interface can not require all implementers to meet certain asymptotic performance requirements. Note further from the documentation for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` that "[i]f `Count` is less than the capacity, [`Add`] approaches an `O(1)` operation. If the capacity must be increased to accommodate the new element, this method becomes an `O(n)` operation, where `n` is `Count`." Further, "Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to `O(1)`."  Why they are vague on that last point eludes me.

Comment: It's probably because GetHashCode() is not always implemented correctly, and when there are lots of collisions it's no longer O(1).